# alert box not working in ajax success (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I'm using ajax call in input box onclick event.
when I call alertbox in ajax success it's not working but console.log is working good.
Please help me.

in my view

```
<input id="extention" type="text" value="" onkeyup="SetExtention(event, this.value); return false;" class="form-control terminal_id" />
```

my function

```
    function SetExtention(e, item) {
        console.log("SetExtention");
        e.preventDefault();

        if (item != "") {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {   //Enter Event

                var inputLine = $('#extention').val().split(',');

                if (inputLine.length == 0)
                    return;
                else {
                    $('#hdnLastExtention').val(inputLine[inputLine.length - 1]);

                    for (var i = 0; i < inputLine.length; i++) {

                        $.ajax({
                            url: urls,
                            type: 'GET',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            data: {
                                ID: inputLine[i]
                            },
                            cache: false,
                            async:false,
                            success: function (result) {
                               alert("aaaaaaaa");
                               console.log("aaaaaa");

                                if (result.isSuccess == false) {

                                    doing some work...
                                }

                                if ($('#hdnLastExtention').val() == result.inputData)
                                {
                                    alert("alert box doesn't appear.");
                                    console.log("alert box doesn't appear.");
                                }

                            },
                            error: function (request, error) {
                                console.log("It has error");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }

        }
}
```

Finally, that's the result of console (I attached the image to make clear the results.)

I can see the console log but alert box doesn't work.

[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hqhqi.png)

Comment: I just forgot to inform that I tested in Chrome. I should use Chrome browser only.

Comment: Async false will not change anything

Comment: I suddenly solved this problem. I tried remove chrome history and It's working well. I don't know why, but I guess it was cookie or cashed data problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when you tick the confirm box for "Stop this page from creating pop-ups".

Do try, close the tab and open a new window and try.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in the script tag has type="text/javascript" attribute.

eg;

```
<script  type="text/javascript">

    // Your function

</script>
```